# Tcl crange vs. string range

Tags: string, tcl

Why does the [Tcl wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1991) say to consider `string range` over `crange`? I know that `crange` is TclX and `string range` is not, but are there any other differences? And if not, then why does `crange` exist?

Comment: I suspect they are the same, but I guess @DonalFerrows is the best person who can answer considering he wrote this wiki :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`crange` has a slightly extended syntax for the index expressions. If you don't need that syntax (and you probably won't) you should use the core command `string range` instead since it lets you avoid the dependency on TclX and makes your code more readable to people unfamiliar with the extension.

`crange` probably won't disappear from TclX anytime soon since that would break old code, but consider it deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

The `crange` command is older and part of an extension package, TclX, that has been the source of many features now in Tcl itself. `string range` can be considered to be the core of Tcl adopting `crange` in spirit. Admittedly, the adoption happened a long time ago (9/6/91 according to the Tcl `changes` file, so it was a new feature in Tcl 6.0).

The recommendation on the Wiki page should be followed; don't use `crange` for new code.

Comment: It does work with non-ASCII input, at least. I'll withdraw my approval :)

Comment: @PeterLewerin I wasn't sure whether it was UTF-8 aware; the code involved is rather elderly after all.

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to add deprecation notices to the TclX documentation and change the wording on the wiki? The phrase "consider using X instead" seemed to me to indicate an extremely mild recommendation, as in "think about it, but do as you please", not at all at the "do not use" level.